# Adding to shopping cart [Drag and Drop]

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I am trying to create a Virtual Shopping basket.

1. There will be items [from database]
2. There will be  a virtual basket
3. Users can drag the items and put inside basket. [Like buying in a shopping mall].
4. After user clicked save button, the shopping cart will be saved.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Yes.It's possible by using: SQL , PHP and jqueryUI(or any other library).

Comment: is there any link? It is similar to google+ circles.

Comment: `Google` it. There are dozens of tutorials. Actually , you even can google something like "item drag-and-drop php jquery".

Comment: okay Ofir Baruch , I will try. Will update my questions when I find more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You’ll need a couple technologies.

1. HTML5/CSS3 to position and style the items and cart
2. jQuery UI with the drag and drop effects: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
3. ajax to send the dragged/dropped items to a PHP handler
4. PHP to store the items in a session and process the transaction

Comment: thanks I found what I am looking for here.. http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd2.php

Comment: sorry can't vote up , rep too low :)

Comment: That’s fine. Can you mark as the solution?